# RecyclerView not showing up properly (scrunched up)

Tags: android, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-toolbar, android-cardview

I've been trying to implement multiple `RecyclerView` within a layout that is part of a collapsing tab. However, my `RecyclerView` hasn't been working and I don't know what I did wrong in my code. Please help me!

Here is the Github Link: github.com/arxbombus/RecipeDetails

Here is the desired view: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jzeks.png)

Here is what I'm getting for some reason: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aHvu1.png)

As you can see, everything is all scrunched up. :(

Below I've included the layouts for my `MainActivity` and also the Java files for my Adapters.

**Here is my `activity_main.xml`**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="400dp"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            app:title="Some Randome Recipe"
            app:titleEnabled="true"
            app:contentScrim="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/ivParallax"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:src="@drawable/food"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                app:layout_collapseParallaxMultiplier="0.7" />

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light"
                app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar" />
        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
        android:id="@+id/nestedScrollView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtAbout"
                android:text="About this recipe"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-25dp"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtRecipeDescription"
                android:text="@string/recipe_description"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-5dp"
                android:textSize="12sp"/>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDivider"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtInfo"
                android:text="Info"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvRecipeInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="75dp"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDivider"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtIngredient"
                android:text="Ingredients"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvRecipeIngredient"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Button" />

            <View
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@color/colorDivider"
                android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
                />


            walking
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/txtProcedures"
                android:text="Procedures"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:textSize="13sp"
                android:padding="15dp"
                android:layout_marginBottom="-20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="-5dp"/>

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvRecipeProcedure"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                android:padding="15dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>



        </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**And my `CardView`**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/recipeInfoCards"
    android:layout_width="81dp"
    android:layout_height="75dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
    android:elevation="15dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@color/colorRecipeInfoCardBG"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">


    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRecipeInfoCardTitle"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Cooking Time:"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/txtRecipeInfoCardDescription"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="20 Minutes"
        android:textSize="11sp"
        android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"/>


</LinearLayout>

</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

**And here are my `MainActivity` and Adapters respectiviely**

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  ArrayList < Recipe > recipeData;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN,
      WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    recipeData = new ArrayList < Recipe > ();
    createData();


    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    if (getSupportActionBar() != null) {
      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    }

    RecyclerView recipeInfoCardRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvRecipeInfo);
    recipeInfoCardRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recipeInfoCardRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    RecipeInfoAdapter recipeInfoAdapter = new RecipeInfoAdapter(this, recipeData);
    recipeInfoCardRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL, false));
    recipeInfoCardRV.setAdapter(recipeInfoAdapter);

    RecyclerView recipeIngredientRV = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.rvRecipeIngredient);
    recipeIngredientRV.setHasFixedSize(true);
    recipeIngredientRV.setNestedScrollingEnabled(false);
    recipeIngredientRV.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false));
    RecipeIngredientAdapter recipeIngredientAdapter = new RecipeIngredientAdapter(this, recipeData);
    recipeIngredientRV.setAdapter(recipeIngredientAdapter);
  }

  public void createData() {
    ArrayList < RecipeInfoCard > recipeInfoCards = new ArrayList < RecipeInfoCard > ();
    recipeInfoCards.add(new RecipeInfoCard("Cooking Time", "20 Minutes"));
    recipeInfoCards.add(new RecipeInfoCard("Calories", "3501"));
    recipeInfoCards.add(new RecipeInfoCard("Procedures", "Three"));


    ArrayList < RecipeIngredient > recipeIngredients = new ArrayList < RecipeIngredient > ();
    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
      recipeIngredients.add(new RecipeIngredient("Ingredient " + i, String.valueOf(i), "grams"));
    }

    Recipe dm = new Recipe(recipeInfoCards, recipeIngredients);
    recipeData.add(dm);
  }

}
```

**My adapter for my `CardView`**

```js
public class RecipeInfoAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter < RecipeInfoAdapter.RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder > {

  private Context mContext;
  private ArrayList < Recipe > recipeData;

  public RecipeInfoAdapter(Context mContext, ArrayList < Recipe > recipeData) {
    this.mContext = mContext;
    this.recipeData = recipeData;
  }

  @Override
  public RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.recipe_info_card_view, null);
    return new RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder(v);
  }

  @Override
  public void onBindViewHolder(RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder recipeInfoCardItemRowHolder, int position) {
    Recipe recipe = recipeData.get(position);
    recipeInfoCardItemRowHolder.infoCardTitle.setText(recipe.getRecipeInfoCards().get(position).getRecipeInfoCardTitle());
    recipeInfoCardItemRowHolder.infoCardDescription.setText(recipe.getRecipeInfoCards().get(position).getRecipeInfoCardDescription());
  }

  @Override
  public int getItemCount() {
    return (null != recipeData ? recipeData.size() : 0);
  }

  public class RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    protected TextView infoCardTitle;
    protected TextView infoCardDescription;

    public RecipeInfoCardItemRowHolder(View view) {
      super(view);
      this.infoCardTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecipeInfoCardTitle);
      this.infoCardDescription = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtRecipeInfoCardDescription);
    }
  }
}
```

I didn't put all my code here because I think the question is long enough but I would really appreciate if someone helped me. Thank you!

Comment: can u explain more about it

Comment: any exception...?

Comment: @NileshRathod I'm trying to create a RecyclerView but for some reason it is no showing up properly and I don't know why. I added several elements to it but it is showing up only as one of the elements and everything is scrunched up.

Comment: My go to "debugging" technique for layout problems such as this is to give some ugly, but flashy color to each view I am thinking might be a part of the problem and then see what overlays what or how much space does a certain view occupy vs. what I thought it would. You can also try Hierarchy Viewer.

Comment: @lidkxx could you elaborate more? I'm a complete newbie to Java and programming in general so I don't quite know what you mean

Comment: @Harrison can your share your project

Comment: You can add background color to your layout elements in XML e.g. android:background="#fff000" then run your app and see where each element is being drawn. This should give you some idea about what could possibly be wrong in your layout rendering i.e. a layout being to small for the content or layouts drawn on top on each other where they shouldn't be.

Comment: @NileshRathod Great idea! Here it is, and I also put it in my question: [Github Link](https://github.com/arxbombus/RecipeDetails)

Comment: i will try and update you @Harrison

Comment: activity_main.xml line 143 remove "walking" :) Although there's more to your problem I'm sure.

Comment: @lidkxx haha idk how that got in there

Comment: r u there @Harrison

Comment: @NileshRathod yes

Answer (score 0):

Try to change your rvRecipeInfo RecyclerView height.. becasue your hardicoading it to 75 dp which is wrong.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:id="@+id/rvRecipeInfo"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
                android:orientation="horizontal"
                android:padding="15dp"></android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
```

similer to cardview as well

```
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/recipeInfoCards"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="75dp"
        app:cardCornerRadius="6dp"
        android:elevation="15dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/colorRecipeInfoCardBG"
        android:padding="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical">


        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipeInfoCardTitle"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Cooking Time:"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
    />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txtRecipeInfoCardDescription"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="20 Minutes"
            android:textSize="11sp"
            android:textColor="@color/colorTextSecondary"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="center"/>


    </LinearLayout>

    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: yes but the other RecyclerView, the one for the Ingredients also isn't working and all that is is a Layout with some TextViews in it

Comment: recipeInfoCardRV.setHasFixedSize(true);   remove this property and try again

Comment: Still not working :( It still looks the same as it did before. I think it may be a problem with either the way I'm adding data or my Layout in activity_main but I'm a newbie to java so I don't know

Comment: your recyclerview implementation is fine. I guess some problem with the xml only. please check my updated answer for cardview

Comment: I'm guessing it's my activity_main.xml because it still doesn't work after replacing my cardview xml with your answer